# watcher ignores changes in the store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I have a component for displaying paginated elements in a table.

I've rewritten pagination to be based on Vuex (previously it was using Event Bus) and it almost works - the values are saved to the store, but my watcher is unable to catch up the changes.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input-number
            class="data-table__pagination__form-group"
            :min="min"
            :max="maxPerPage"
            :step="step"
            :label="messages.inputNumber__label"
            v-model.number="perPageComputed"
        />
        <b-pagination
            class="data-table__pagination__list"
            v-model="currentPageComputed"
            :total-rows="totalRows"
            :per-page="perPageComputed"
            :limit="1"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import bPagination from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/pagination/pagination';
import InputNumber from '@/components/forms/InputNumber';

export default {
    name: 'DataTablePagination',

    components: { InputNumber },

    extends: bPagination,

    props: {
        module: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    },

    data () {
        return {
            min: 5,
            step: 5,
            messages: {
                inputNumber__label: 'Rows per page:',
            },
        };
    },

    computed: {
        maxPerPage () {
            return Math.min(100, this.totalRows);
        },
        currentPageComputed: {
            get: function () {
                return this.$store.getters.page(this.module);
            },
            set: function (newValue) {
                this.$store.commit('CHANGE_PAGE', {key: this.module, value: {page: newValue}});
            },
        },
        perPageComputed:     {
            get: function () {
                return this.$store.getters.perPage(this.module);
            },
            set: function (newValue) {
                this.$store.commit('CHANGE_PER_PAGE', {key: this.module, value: {perPage: newValue}});
            },
        },
    },

    watch: {
        currentPageComputed (value) {
            console.log('watching currentPageComputed', value); // never appears
        },
        perPageComputed (value) {
            console.log('watching perPageComputed', value); // never appears
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

I have a store structure like this:

```
{
    (...),
    list: {
        someModuleName: {
            page:    1,
            perPage: 10
        }
    }
}
```

Store module:

```
import * as types from '@/store/types';

// initial state
const state = {
    banners: {},
};

// getters
const getters = {
    page (state) {
        return module => (state[module].page : 1);
    },
    perPage (state) {
        return module => (state[module].perPage : 10);
    },
};  

// mutations
const mutations = {
    [types.CHANGE_PAGE] (state, {key, value}) {
        state[key] = Object.assign(state[key], value);
    },
    [types.CHANGE_PER_PAGE] (state, {key, value}) {
        state[key] = Object.assign(state[key], value);
    },
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
};
```

So whenever current page or row limit (perPage) changes I'd like to be notified so I can pull the data with correct offset. But for some reason the watcher doesn't work.

I tried to change store actions from `commit` to `dispatch` and listen on the parent component but watcher still remains blind on page or row limit change.

Comment: Could you include your store in as well, it might help seeing the actions/mutations there are

Comment: It's very likely related to the way you mutate the store in your mutation, check this page : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats and try to keep your store as flat as possible

Comment: Updated the question with store module. @nicolast yes, it must be somehow related, I'm merging the old state with new object, so `CHANGE_PER_PAGE` mutation won't overwrite `page`. I don't know how to redesign it to flatter structure because I'd rather keep page data for each module in one store, than duplicate the page change action for each module store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to create a new Object when mutating the state:

```
// mutations
const mutations = {
    [types.CHANGE_PAGE] (state, {key, value}) {
        state[key] = Object.assign({}, state[key], value);
    },
    [types.CHANGE_PER_PAGE] (state, {key, value}) {
        state[key] = Object.assign({}, state[key], value);
    },
};
```